# Android java performance: invoking static method from self class or outer class

Tags: java, android, performance, static

by an high-performance point of view, calling an outer class `static` method is slower than calling a `static` method in the same class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, never. Leaving method visibility apart, static method are just global function in the C sense. So it can't matter, what class they belong to, not even on Android.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  Consider the following:

```
public class Outer {
    /*private*/ static void outerMethod() {
        // do stuff
    }

    static class Inner {
        public void doStuff() {
            outerMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

The `doStuff()` method's bytecode looks like this:

```
     0: invokestatic  #2                  // Method Outer.outerMethod:()V
     3: return
```

But if we make `outerMethod()` private, the code will look like this instead:

```
     0: invokestatic  #2                  // Method Outer.access$000:()V
     3: return
```

The problem is that the inner class can't directly call the outer class method, because it's private.  The compiler works around this by creating a synthetic `access$000()` method, which does nothing but call `outerMethod()`.  Calling through the accessor method is slower unless the AOT or JIT compiler recognizes the pattern and optimizes it out.

So, calling an outer-class static method *could* be slower if it's also declared private.