# Difference between package class and private static inner class in Java?

Tags: java, performance, dalvik

If if I have two classes `Thing` and `ThingAdapter` where `ThingAdapter` is only used in class `Thing`, is there a performance (or otherwise) difference between defining `ThingAdapter` as a static inner class of `Thing` vs a package scope class alongside it?

The scenario I'm looking at has `ThingAdapter` being used somewhat like

```
public class Thing {
    private ThingAdapter thingAdapter;
    public doStuff() {
        thingAdapter = new ThingAdapter();
    }
}
```

And `ThingAdapter` could be implemented either like

```
public class Thing {
    // stuff

    private static class ThingAdapter {
        // adapter stuff
    }
}
```

versus

```
public class Thing {
    // stuff
}

/* package */ class ThingAdapter {
    // adapter stuff
}
```

The environment I'm currently working in is Android, and I haven't seen any performance differences between the two yet—without actually benchmarking it though. Also, would Dalvik and JVM treat this differently?

Comment: Real difference is so: first class is in class and with name `Thing$ThingAdapter`, the second is just `ThingAdapter`. So there's no difference.

Comment: There can be performance consequences if you call private methods.  The code in the question doesn't, so there's no difference.  (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210531/android-java-performance-invoking-static-method-from-self-class-or-outer-class/24214350#24214350 .)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No appreciable performance differences. In this case class design should not impact performances. A good approach is to write code to be as clear as possible for the developer, then to profile it to find bottlenecks (if required) and then optimize only the code affected.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to make sure I'm not setting myself up for failure in the future.